# IronSource Rewards video load

Tags: android, android-studio, rewardedvideoad, ironsource

I'm using `IronSource` for mediating rewards video. The first time it works OK but there's no way of loading the reward video second time without killing the app.

I checked their SDK and there's no `loadReward` or `requestReward` in their API. The first video loads automatically when `IronSource.init(context, mAppKey, IronSource.AD_UNIT.REWARDED_VIDEO)` is called.

How can I load the second reward video?

Comment: Have you solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the capping and pacing settings - that could be why you're having issues.

You can also use:

```
boolean available = IronSource.isRewardedVideoAvailable();
```

to check if you have availability for rewarded video.

Comment: yes but I'm looking for a way to upload the video once it has finished to upload a new one. I have contacted support but they are slow to respond.